# EasyPHP Devserver install on windows 10

Tags: easyphp

I've got it installed, and I think it's working because I can get to the dashboard. But I can't browse to the files in the document root - I'm getting err_conection_refused using localhost or 127.0.0.1

The EasyPHP icon is not flashing it's red square. And I can't tell is Apache and/or MySQL is up and running - where's the status?

Answer (score 0):

It should say on the top of the dashboard the status of both the Web server and the MySQL server. Pic: http://prntscr.com/ct6lke